#  Insert new object with existing object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new to EF 4 and this is what I have done so far:

- Create an edmx file based on my database
- Create a code generation for my objects (POCO). Now I have a model1.tt, when expanded I see al my classes
- Create a repository for each class, based on IRepository

Now, I am working with two objects, A and B. Object A has a property of type B. In my winform I have a combo filled with objects of type B. When the save button is pressed, a new instance of class A is created and all the properties are set. The object B property is set as follows:

```
objectA.myObjectB = (objectB)cmbBObjects.selectedItem;
```

Then I create a repository for objectA and call the save method. In this save method I have this code±

```
public bool Save(ObjectA obj)
{
  using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
  {
    context.objectAs.AddObject(obj);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

This code, does save a new entry to the database, but it is also creating a new record for object B! I don't want this, because object B already exists in the database! (I have selected this one from the combobox).

This is how I fill my combobox:

In the objectB repository:

```
public IList<ObjectB> GetAll()
{
    using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        IList<ObjectB> objects = context.objectBs.ToList();
        return objects;
    }
}
```

In my form:

```
ObjectBRepository rep = new ObjectBRepository();
IList<ObjectB> objects = rep.GetAll;

cmbBObjects.Datasource = objects;
// etc..
```

So my question is, what do I have to do to save object A without creating a new record for objectB?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't want insert `objectB` you must inform EF about it. When you call `context.objectAs.AddObject(obj)` for `objectA` you are saying: *I want to insert objectA and all its dependencies*. But obviously you don't want to save dependecies so you must either:

- Load `objectB` from DB before adding it to `objectA`. In such case EF will know that `objectB` is existing object and it will not insert it again.
- Attach `objectB` to context before adding it to `objectA`. `ObjectB` will be handled as existing but unchanged.
- Set the state of `objectB` after inserting `objectA`. You can do that by calling: `context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(objectB, EntityState.Unchanged)`

Example of the fist suggestion:

```
var id = objectB.Id;
objectA.myObjectB = context.ObjectBs.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
```

Example of the second suggestion:

```
context.ObjectBs.Attach(objectB);
objectA.myObjectB = objectB;
```

Example of the third suggestion:

```
objectA.myObjectB = objectB;
context.ObjectAs.AddObject(objectA);
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(objectB, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand suggestion 1. The second suggestion: In the repository of objectA, do something like: `var obj = context.ObjectB.where(b=> b.Id == objectA.myObjectB.Id).firstOrDefault(); context.ObjectA.Attach(obj); ` Is this correct?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Exactly, all possible options, and i suppose second option best one for above example. +1

Comment: I've tried your second solution, but slightly different. In my Save method of my ObjectA repository I had this: `context.objectBs.Attach(objectA.myObjectB); context.objectAs.AddObject(objectA); context.SaveChanges();` But here I got a key alreaydy exists exception at line `context.objectAs.AddObject(objectA);` Why was that?

Comment: You must `Attach` `objectB` before you assing it to `objectA` otherwise you will attach both objects and you will not be able to add `objectA`.

Comment: @Martijn: You should attach objectB to context after you get it from dataContext and only objectB not objectA.

Comment: So, when I had done it this way: `var objB = objectA.objectB; context.objectBs.Attach(objB); //etc..` It had worked?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because my Save method of objectA has one argument: Objecta: `public bool Save(objectA)` Otherwise I have to create a Save method with an argument for each object and I don't think this is the way to go..

Comment: @Martijn: no, *var b = (objectB)cmbBObjects.selectedItem;* than *context.objectBs.Attach(b);* than assign to objectA and call *Save* method.

Comment: In case of using repositorie the best option is the first one. Otherwise you will have to modify your repositories to support these scenarios.

Comment: Thnx. But is it desireable to have the context in the UI layer? I don't think so, because the UI layer is then directly talking to the data layer. So I have to solve this in my repository, right?

Comment: Sure you will ask repositoryB to get the object and assign it to `objectA`. But be aware that you must share context among repositories. As you can see repository generally doesn't make things easier.

Comment: And what is the best way to share the context between repositories? And if the repositories are shared, where is the context created for the first time? Who/what is responsible for that?

Comment: Welcome to the word of architecture. The answers you are looking for are: unit of work and dependency injection / inversion of control.

Comment: Hehe, thnx. Do you know a website that can point me at the right direction to start with?

Comment: Actually no. I'm web / wcf developer so I don't know how this is usually handled in WinForms / WPF (ok I have an idea but it is just a theory). But you can ask another question about it and hopefully somebody else will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that problem in following row:

```
objectA.myObjectB = (objectB)cmbBObjects.selectedItem;
```

Because of result `(objectB)cmbBObjects.selectedItem` detached from datacontext entity framework create new instance. Instead this you can:

1.Assign objectB id to objectA

```
var b = (objectB)cmbBObjects.selectedItem;
objectA.myObjectBId = b.Id;
```

2.Or load objectB from dataContext and than assign to objectA:

```
var b = (objectB)cmbBObjects.selectedItem;
var dcB = context.ObjectBs.Single(x=> x.Id == b.Id);
objectA.myObjectB = dcB;
```

Just try my suggestions and come back with results, because i don't know exactly.

Hope this help.

Comment: objectA does not have a objectB id directly, this must be set as follows (I suppose) `objectA..myObjectB.Id = b.Id` But, I think this will throw an argumentNull exception, because the `.myObjectB` property is not set. The second solution: I don't think I want my context in the winform, I'd like to keep that object in my repositories.

Comment: @Martijn: Okay, than you should go second way suggested by me(load objectB from dataContext and assign to objectA).