# Adding new object with related existing object insert new row for existing object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a simple relationship:

I have a "Note" object, which has a related "Company" object. 
When creating a "Note", you select an existing "Company", and enter the other neccessary fields.

My issue is that whenever I save, it inserts a new version of the "Company" object, and I can't figure out why.

I have tried all the options in the accepted answer here  [Insert new object with existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416323/c-sharp-entity-framework-4-insert-new-object-with-existing-object) but nothing works.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
var company = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == note.Company.ID);
note.Company = company;

db.Notes.AddObject(note);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(company, EntityState.Unchanged);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(note, EntityState.Added);

db.SaveChanges();
```

But, it keeps adding a new "Company" object. What is strange, is that it doesn't add all the fields, just the CompanyName" field, (and creates a new Id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an existing company, set the CompantID field and not the entity

```
note.CompanyID = company.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your first line when use use note.Company.Id in the FirstorDefault method. If you could post the entrie method I may be able to help further. If you have companyId as a parameter coming into the method then you could rework the code above as follows:

```
Company company = db.Company.Find(companyId);
note.Company = company;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or as the other answer suggests just set note.CompanyId

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating a new instance of `Note` and setting the `Company` property therefore EF which I assume is re-creating the company record. If you are trying to link your `Note` to an existing `Company` object them just set the foreign key for the company on the note e.g.

```
var company = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == note.Company.ID);    
note.CompanyID = company.ID; // will link the note to the specified company
db.Notes.AddObject(note);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It also doesn't make sense that you are using `note.Company.ID` to pull the company down, this property should be `null` if it's a new `Note`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it, hope it helps.

```
using (DataContext dtx = new DataContext()) {

            Note note = new Note();

            dtx.Notes.Add(note);

            Company company = dtx.Companies.FirstOrDefault((System.Object obj) => obj.ServerId == 1);

            note.Server = company;

            dtx.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every ones responses.

My problem in the end was, firstly, when creating my model for the page, I instantiated an initial new "Company", so I set company to null for creating.

Then, on the page, I had Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName,.... (it's an auto complete ajax text box that sets a hidden companyID field when chosen) when was meaning a new Company object was getting passed back to the controller.

I did try setting this to null before setting the company ID, but that didn't work.
However, removing the above textboxfor bit, everything started working!