# How to properly save a complex object using EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have a problem with saving a complex object...
The (simplified) objects look like this:

```
public class Excavator
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ExcavatorType Type { get; set; } = new();

        public IList<ExcavatorProperty> Properties { get; set; } = new List<ExcavatorProperty>();

        public IList<SparePart> SpareParts { get; set; } = new List<SparePart>();
    }

public class ExcavatorType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IList<ExcavatorPropertyType> PropertyTypes { get; set; } = new List<ExcavatorPropertyType>();

        public IList<Excavator> ExcavatorsOfThisType { get; set; } = new List<Excavator>();
    }

public class ExcavatorProperty
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ExcavatorPropertyType PropertyType { get; set; } = null!;
    }

public class SparePart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IList<Excavator> Excavators { get; set; } = new List<Excavator>();
    }

public class ExcavatorPropertyType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IList<ExcavatorType> ExcavatorTypesWithThisProperty { get; set; } = new List<ExcavatorType>()!;
    }
```

What I want to do is save `excavator` (which is of type `Excavator`). Instances of `ExcavatorType` and `SparePart`s already exist in the database (so are `ExcavatorPropertyType`s).

I filled `excavator` with data from form and after reading the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416323/insert-new-object-with-existing-object#answer-5416481) I tried the following:

```
var excavatorTypeTmp = await context.ExcavatorTypes
    .FirstAsync(et => et.Id == excavator.Type.Id);
excavator.Type = excavatorTypeTmp;

var sparePartsIds = excavator.SpareParts.Select(sp => sp.Id);
excavator.SpareParts = await context.SpareParts
    .Where(sp => sparePartsIds.Contains(sp.Id))
    .ToListAsync();

context.Add(excavator);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Error I got: "*The instance of entity type 'ExcavatorType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.*"

I also tried `.Attach()` and `.AttachRange()`:

```
context.Attach(excavator.Type);
context.AttachRange(excavator.SpareParts);

context.Add(excavator);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Error I got: "*The instance of entity type 'Excavator' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.*"

Then I even tried (because of some comments in the previously mentioned question):

```
var typeTmp = excavator.Type;
excavator.Type = null!;
context.Attach(typeTmp);
excavator.Type = typeTmp;

var sparePartsTmp = excavator.SpareParts;
excavator.SpareParts = null!;
context.AttachRange(sparePartsTmp);
excavator.SpareParts = sparePartsTmp;

context.Add(excavator);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Errot I got: The same as the previous one.

If I'm not mistaken the problem occurs when we try to attach spare parts (`context.AttachRange(sparePartsTmp);`).

Another thing I found out is that when I'm not saving spare parts, there is no problem. The excavator seems to save correctly (but without spare parts of course).

So I thought that maybe the problem is that I reference the same excavator entities (I try to attach the multiple excavators with the same id) both from `excavator.Type` and `excavator.SpareParts`.
And when I tried to save it this way (I got rid of references to `excavator`s from spare parts by assigning null)...:

```
context.Attach(excavator.Type);

var excavatorsTmp = new List<IList<Excavator>>(excavator.SpareParts.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < excavator.SpareParts.Count; i++)
{
    var sparePart = excavator.SpareParts[i];
    excavatorsTmp.Add(sparePart.Excavators);
    sparePart.Excavators = null!;
}
context.AttachRange(excavator.SpareParts);

context.Add(excavator);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

...it seems to work fine- the excavator was saved correctly.
But I believe there is some other (more reasonable) way how to save `excavator`.

**Edit (more info):**

I am using `using` statement (*using declaration* to be precise). I create `context` like this:

```
using var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
```

Where `.CreateDbContext()` looks like this:

```
var connectionString = GetConnectionString();
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

I did it this way because it's a Blazor (server side) app and I have seen it done like this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor).

Comment: The issue is with "NEW" when you are creating instances of the class.  When you first start the project a query is made to the database that fill the dbContext.  So you do not have to create the context in your code that was created during the initial fill of the context.  So I think the error is with the new List<xyz> statements in the classes.

Comment: @jdweng I refactored the code so now I don't have these new List<xyz> there as you have mentioned. Now when I tried to save `excavator` I still got "The instance of entity type 'Excavator' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. " 

I tried it both with and without `.Attach()`/`.AttachRange()` and also with `.Add()` and `.Update()`. But still getting the same error.

Comment: The issue is how you create a instance of your  dbContext. Try 'Using' statement and it will work for you mentioned in this tutorial. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/update-data-in-entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's the problem. I am using `using` statement. Maybe I should have written it in there too, I'll edit the question and add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found out the cause of the problem. The code here is simplified, the actual code is a bit more complex. And in some part of the code (which is not shown here) I was adding to list property of a tracked entity instances **NOT** from the db context. And it seems that was causing the problems.

*More detailed explanation:* Unfortunately, I can't remember exactly which code caused the problem and which code solved the problem as there were multiple iterations of changes...  But as I mentioned earlier my problem was solved by saving only instances from the context.

Let's say we have "new" `excavator` variable from the "outside" (untracked entity) which we want to save and "old" `currentExcavator` from the `context` (i.e. from the database), both are of type `Excavator`. These objects have some list properties (e.g. `SpareParts`). We can `Add` and `Remove` things from these list properties.
Now let's say we have figured out *somehow* that `excavator` has 1 *new spare part* in the `SpareParts`  which `currentExcavator` doesn't have. Thus we want to call `currentExcavator.Add(X)` where `X` is the *new spare part* (and then `context.SaveChangesAsync()` of course).

The problem was that the `X` I was adding was **NOT** from the context. I should have done `context.SpareParts.First(sp => sp.Id == newSparePartId)` to get `X` (where `newSparePartId` is the id of the *new spare part* a.k.a `X`).

The method I use for saving `Excavator` instances can be found [here](https://github.com/milantru/ServIS/blob/main/ServIS/ServISData/ServISApi.cs#L21).

Comment: How DID you fix it? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can find more detailed explanation there now which I hope will help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.Update(yourEntity)` insted of `context.Add(yourEntity)`.

`.Update()` will detect if it's an insert or update of existing entity and will act accordingly. [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-6.0)

Comment: When I used only `context.Update(excavator);` without `.Attach()`/`.AttachRange()` I got an error: "*The instance of entity type 'Excavator' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached*".

When I used also `context.Attach(excavator.Type);` and `context.AttachRange(excavator.SpareParts);` before calling `.Update()` the same error has occured.